# Entity Framework Core navigations not updating

Tags: entity-framework-core

I'm using Entity Framework Core v5.0.3 for this.

I'm making a simple information app for users where each user can have favourite colours.

Person model

```
public class Person 
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public bool IsAuthorised { get; set; }
    public bool IsValid { get; set; }
    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<FavouriteColour> FavouriteColours { get; set; }
}
```

Favourite colour model

```
public class FavouriteColour
{
    [Key]
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public int ColourId { get; set; }
    public virtual Colour Colour { get; set; }
}
```

Colour model

```
public class Colour
{
    [Key]
    public int ColourId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<FavouriteColour> FavouriteColours { get; set; }
}
```

In my database context I've defined them as so

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
{
        modelBuilder.Entity<FavouriteColour>()
            .HasKey(c => new { c.PersonId, c.ColourId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<FavouriteColour>()
            .HasOne(fc => fc.Person)
            .WithMany(p => p.FavouriteColours)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.PersonId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<FavouriteColour>()
            .HasOne(fc => fc.Colour)
            .WithMany(c => c.FavouriteColours)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.ColourId);
}
```

Now in the app a user can add or remove favourite colours so a new user object is received in the controller which calls the repository update

```
public async Task<IActionResult> PutPerson(int id, Person person) 
{
    peopleRepository.Update(person);
}
```

The repository then does the update

```
public void Update(Person person) 
{
    _context.Update(person);
}
```

After doing `await _context.SaveChangesAsync();` none of the colours change. I thought the purpose of all these models and such was so the colours would change automatically?

I setup a `FavouriteColourRepository` instead to do the updates like this

```
public async Task<bool> Update(int personId, ICollection<FavouriteColour> favouriteColours) 
{
    // empty their favourite colours
    _context.FavouriteColours.RemoveRange(_context.FavouriteColours.Where(fc => fc.PersonId == personId);

    // add new favourite colours
    _context.FavouriteColours.AddRange(favouriteColours);

    return true;
}
```

And I changed my controller to this

```
public async Task<IActionResult> PutPerson(int id, Person person)
{
    peopleRepository.Update(person);
    bool valid = await favouriteColourRepository.Update(id, person.FavouriteColours);
}
```

But for some reason I can't figure out

```
_context.FavouriteColours.RemoveRange(_context.FavouriteColours.Where(fc => fc.PersonId == personId);
```

actually alters the favouriteColours parameter and forces the last state into it which creates duplicate primary keys and the inserting fails.

So why do the new favourite colours never get inserted and why is my `favouriteColours` parameter being edited when I'm trying to clear all the colours a user already has?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why do the new favourite colours never get inserted

The call `_context.Update(person);` puts the `Person` entity and all is related `FavouriteColour` entity in `Modified` state. Hence, on the next `SaveChanges` call EF is supposed to submit update commands to the database.

If you modify any property of the `Person` entity, you'll find that the person has been updated correctly. The issue with the `FavouriteColour` entity is that it contains nothing but the primary key properties, and EF does not modify the key property (or any property that is part of a composite primary key). You can test this with the following code -

```cs
var fc = dbCtx.FavouriteColours
        .FirstOrDefault(p => p.PersonId == 1 && p.ColourId == 4);
                    
fc.ColourId = 6;    // CoulourId is part of primary key
dbCtx.SaveChanges();
```

and you will be met with an exception -

> The property 'FavouriteColour.ColourId' is part of a key and so cannot
> be modified or marked as modified. ...

Therefore, EF will not even generate any update command for the `FavouriteColours`, even though all of them are marked as `Modified`.

To update the `Person` and all its `FavouriteColour` you need to do something like -

```cs
// fetch the exising person with all its FavouriteColours
var existingPerson = dbCtx.Persons
                    .Include(p => p.FavouriteColours)
                    .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
                    
// modify any properties of Person if you need

// replace the existing FavouriteColours list
existingPerson.FavouriteColours = person.FavouriteColours;

// save the changes
dbCtx.SaveChanges();
```

This will -

1. delete any `FavouriteColour` that are in the existing list but not in the new list
2. insert any `FavouriteColour` that are in the new list but not in the existing list.

With your repositories in place, its up to you how you implement this.

> why is my favouriteColours parameter being edited when I'm trying to
> clear all the colours a user already has

Before this operation you called `_context.Update(person);`. Therefore, `Person` is now being tracked in `Modified` state as an existing entity. Then when you called -

```cs
_context.FavouriteColours.RemoveRange(_context.FavouriteColours.Where(fc => fc.PersonId == personId));
```

the `_context.FavouriteColours.Where(fc => fc.PersonId == personId)` part, fetched the existing `FavouriteColours` of that `Person` from the database. So these fetched `FavouriteColours` are added to the person's `FavouriteColours` list (because it is being tracked).

For example, lets say in your controller you received a `Person` entity with 4 `FavouriteColour`, and the database has 3 `FavouriteColour` for this person. After calling `_context.Update(person);`, the person is being tracked with a list of 4 `FavouriteColour`. Then when you fetched this person's existing `FavouriteColours` from the database, the person is being tracked with a list of total 7 `FavouriteColour`.

I hope that shades any light.